# Extract image Scrolldown issue using Tableau REST API in python

Tags: python, image, api, rest, tableau-api

I want to extract image from Tableau workbook using REST API in python.
I am able to get token for Tableau authentication and fetch corresponding workbook and view id.

When i am extracting image using API like :-

url = "http://tableau.xyz.com/api/3.7/sites/bfda4337123971272/views/b55-83e229905e17/image?image-resolution=high"

I am able to save the response in png image and able to get the output of worksheet in image but when the worksheet has large detailed data with long scroll down bar, the image is not getting fully extracted. The response size is less than 50 MB which is maximum limit .

Can someone please suggest if we need to add any other options in GET URL in python.

Answer (score 0):

That’s how requesting an image works here.

If your view is a worksheet instead of a dashboard or story, you can paginate it by putting a field on the pages shelf, and using the Page Setup menu command in Tableau Desktop to specify page formatting details.

Another option is design your dashboard to fit on a page and then have a filter or parameter that allows you to paginate through data. (You can pass a filter or parameter setting with the URL)

Typically, you want to design a version of your Tableau view that is laid out well for printing. You don’t typically get great results by simply printing a view that was designed to be used interactively on a computer screen. That’s less effort than it sounds, because both views can use the same underlying data sources, and many of the same component views.